# Unable to run maven install from Idea for Java 9 (tools.jar not found)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I migrated my project from Java 8 to Java 9. Now when I run maven install on this project inside Intellij Idea it fails with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project tutorial: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]

Idea runs the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\User\workspace\tutorial" -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\User\install\apache-maven-3.3.9 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\User\install\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63961:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.3.2 -s C:\Users\User\.m2\settings.xml install -DskipTests -P localhost
```

It works fine if I run mvn install from Windows command line.

All settings point to Java 9:

```
C:\Users\User>java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

C:\Users\User>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1

C:\Users\User>echo %JRE_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1

C:\Users\User>echo %IDEA_JDK%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1

C:\Users\User>echo %IDEA_JDK_64%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
```

In Idea the following settings all point to Java 9:

- Project Structure->Project Settings->Modules->Sources->Language level ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whqul.png))
- Project Structure->Project Settings->Modules->Dependencies->Module
  SDK ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFfXL.png))
- File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build
  Tools->Maven->Runner->JRE ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5ec6.png))

Relevant fragments of my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <testSource>${java.version}</testSource>
        <testTarget>${java.version}</testTarget>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <meminitial>${maven-compiler-meminitial}</meminitial>
        <maxmem>${maven-compiler-maxmem}</maxmem>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>java.se.ee</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<properties>
    <java.version>9</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-meminitial>512m</maven-compiler-meminitial>
    <maven-compiler-maxmem>1024m</maven-compiler-maxmem>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

I would be grateful for any tips what could be wrong.

**Update**

I also noticed, that Idea shows JAVA home as pointing to 1.8 in settings ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFRnP.png)), while environment variables point to 1.9 ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKuzk.png)).

Comment: You might need to update / upgrade intellij. What version are you using?

Comment: My Idea version: Intellij IDEA 2017.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4127.27, built on December 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Try using latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download You can also try starting with default settings (rename/remove settings folders https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519 ) or try using different Maven settings (Maven version, JDK for Maven). Btw does erro do away if you use 1.8 JDK?

Comment: I downloaded latest Idea and made fresh settings folder, however the error still appeared. Everything works fine once I downgrade to 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has similar problem, I was able to fix it by doing the following steps:

- Installed 2018.1 Release Candidate version (suggested on JetBrains forum).
- Changed Maven
  installation in Idea to Bundled.
- Deleted .idea directory in my
  project and reimported it as maven project.

Comment: Deleted .idea directory in my project and reimported it as maven project - did the trick

Answer (score 0):

On startup, intellij determines the JDK in this way. see idea.bat file in the intellij installation directory (bin)

:: Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
:: Try (in order): IDEA_JDK, idea%BITS%.exe.jdk, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have already set IDEA_JDK and IDEA_JDK_64 to the same values as JAVA_HOME. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: if you run mvn clean install outside intellij it works? Then you need to configure intellij to use the same maven installation. CTRL+SHIFT+A -> maven

Comment: It is already using the same maven installation (File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Maven home directory = C:/Users/User/install/apache-maven-3.3.9, mvn -version prints the same directory).

Comment: have you tried with java.version 1.9 instead of 9. :)

Comment: I changed to 1.9 - unfortunately didn't help.